# Add a delay to a set image after animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to click an image, rotate it by 180 degrees and change the image resource. However it doesn't seem to work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

GridLayout gridView;
boolean isGrey = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid);

}

public void flip(final View view){

    ImageView tile = (ImageView) view;
    if(isGrey) {
        tile.animate().rotationXBy(180f).setDuration(700);
        tile.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
        isGrey = false;
    }else{
        tile.animate().rotationXBy(-180f).setDuration(700);
        tile.setImageResource(R.drawable.grey);
        isGrey = true;
    }
    Log.i("Tag", tile.getTag().toString());

}
}
```

All I want to do is change the `setImageResource` after the animation and not instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the withEndAction(Runnable r) method of ViewPropertyAnimator.
Your code should then look something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

GridLayout gridView;
boolean isGrey = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

gridView = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid);

}

public void flip(final View view){

final ImageView tile = (ImageView) view;
if(isGrey) {
    tile.animate().rotationXBy(180f).setDuration(700).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
    tile.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
    isGrey = false;
        }
    });
}else{
    tile.animate().rotationXBy(-180f).setDuration(700).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tile.setImageResource(R.drawable.grey);
            isGrey = true;
        }
    });
}
Log.i("Tag", tile.getTag().toString());

}
}
```